# How to change URL on button click without page redirect in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, meta-tags

I have a page similar to **[this link](https://www.gazelle.com/sell/cell-phone)** which list items. All works fine. Just i am not able to rewrite the `URL` of a `page` on button clicked at different Levels.

EG:
when i click on `Button` "CellPhone" on `Level1 div` and later on click on `Button` "BlackBerry" which is on `Level2 div` then `URL` must be `"www.somesite.com/cellphone/blackberry"` and again when i `click on Button` "cellphone" i must change `URL` to `"www.somesite.com/cellphone"`

Please can any one suggest me to do the same in `asp.net.`

**Note:** **I am using Visual Studio 2008 Framework 3.5**

**Update:**

```
function changeState(num) {
            var stateObj = { foo: "Default" };
            //alert(window.history.length);
            if (num == 1) {
                alert("cellphone");
                window.history.replaceState(stateObj, "HtmlPage", "Cellphone");
                Show("divLevel2");
            }
            else if (num == 2) {
                alert("sprint");

                window.history.replaceState(stateObj, "HtmlPage", "CellPhone/Sprint");
                Show("divLevel3");

            }
            else if (num == 3) {
                alert("iphone6");
                Show("divLevel3");
             window.history.replaceState(stateObj, "HtmlPage","CellPhone/Sprint/iPhone6");


            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            HideAll();

        });
        function Show(divid) {
            $("#" + divid).css("display", "block");

        }
        function HideAll() {
            $("#divLevel2").css("display", "none");
            $("#divLevel3").css("display", "none");

        }
```

**ASPX MARKUP:**

```
 <div class="divMain" class="box">
        <div id="divLevel1" class="box">
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanelLevel1">
                <Triggers>
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="CellPhone" class="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click"
                        ForeColor="Black" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
        <div id="divLevel2" class="box">
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanelLevel2">
                <Triggers>
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Sprint" class="Button2" OnClick="Button2_Click"
                        ForeColor="Black" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
        <div id="divLevel3" class="box">
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanelLevel3">
                <Triggers>
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="iPhone6" class="Button3" OnClick="Button3_Click"
                        ForeColor="Black" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Pagename.ASPX.CS**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "myFunction1", "changeState(1);", true);
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "myFunction2", "changeState(2);", true);
    }
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "myFunction3", "changeState(3);", true);
    }
```

**When i click on "iPhone6" button the click event doesnt fire! any idea?**

Comment: post your asp.net code, will help to understanding more

Comment: @Prog as per your request posted full code! please check the "Update" section in the post

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can't achieve this on the server side, but have to resort to using javascript.

You can manipulate the URL like that, without triggering actual navigation, in browsers that support [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29_method).

In other browsers, you can resort to manipulating the hash part of the URL, which will also not trigger navigation (``)

If you're using jQuery, it could look like this:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
  if(history.pushState){
    //Will become example.com/cellphone/blackberry
    history.pushState(null, '', 'cellphone/blackberry');
  }
  else {
    //Will become example.com#cellphone/blackberry
    window.location.hash = 'cellphone/blackberry'
  }
});
```

Comment: hi @Peter Herdenborg, please check the "UPDATE" in the post. 3rd button click doesnt work! any idea?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE that seems like a completely different question than the original and I notice no credit has been given for our efforts to answer the original question...

Comment: hello @Peter Herdenborg, i didn't get solution from your answer so it has not given any credits and unless problem/issue solved how can i mark as answer? Please dont misunderstand..! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try Below Code**

- You need client script (JavaScript) for this.

`

```
$('#<%= ButtonID.ClientID %>').click(function () {            
     window.location.hash = "blckberry"; //  Change URL with any TEXT************         
    });
```

`

- OR you can use this also.

  `window.history.pushState('obj', 'newtitle', '/blckberry');`

Comment: location.hash will give you #blckberry in URL & your sytax is wrong it must be ClientID instead of Client..